# Elasticnet regression(glmnet) predicting the same value for all observations in test data

Tags: r, glmnet

I'm using the [following](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~post/josh/LASSO_Ridge_Elastic_Net_-_Examples.html) tutorial to try out ridge,lasso and elastic net regression on my own data. However, I get the same value predicted for all rows which can't be true, as a result I also get the same fit and mse values.

I would really appreciate it if someone more knowledgable in R than I'm will have a look at my code and maybe point out what i'm doing wrong. Here it is:

```
library (glmnet)
require(caTools)
set.seed(111) 

new_flat <- fread('RED_SAMPLED_DATA_WITH_HEADERS.csv', header=TRUE, sep = ',') 
sample = sample.split(new_flat$SUBSCRIPTION_ID, SplitRatio = .80)
train = subset(new_flat, sample == TRUE)
test = subset(new_flat, sample == FALSE)

x=model.matrix(c201512_TOTAL_MARGIN~.-SUBSCRIPTION_ID,data=train) 
y=train$c201512_TOTAL_MARGIN

x1=model.matrix(c201512_TOTAL_MARGIN~.-SUBSCRIPTION_ID,data=test) 
y1=test$c201512_TOTAL_MARGIN



# Fit models:
fit.lasso <- glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian", alpha=1)
fit.ridge <- glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian", alpha=0)
fit.elnet <- glmnet(x, y, family="gaussian", alpha=.5)


# 10-fold Cross validation for each alpha = 0, 0.1, ... , 0.9, 1.0
fit.lasso.cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure="mse", alpha=1, 
                          family="gaussian")
fit.ridge.cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure="mse", alpha=0,
                          family="gaussian")
fit.elnet.cv <- cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure="mse", alpha=.5,
                          family="gaussian")

for (i in 0:10) {
  assign(paste("fit", i, sep=""), cv.glmnet(x, y, type.measure="mse", 
                                            alpha=i/10,family="gaussian"))
}


# Plot solution paths:
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
# For plotting options, type '?plot.glmnet' in R console
plot(fit.lasso, xvar="lambda")
plot(fit10, main="LASSO")

plot(fit.ridge, xvar="lambda")
plot(fit0, main="Ridge")

plot(fit.elnet, xvar="lambda")
plot(fit5, main="Elastic Net")


yhat0 <- predict(fit0, s=fit0$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat1 <- predict(fit1, s=fit1$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat2 <- predict(fit2, s=fit2$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat3 <- predict(fit3, s=fit3$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat4 <- predict(fit4, s=fit4$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat5 <- predict(fit5, s=fit5$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat6 <- predict(fit6, s=fit6$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat7 <- predict(fit7, s=fit7$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat8 <- predict(fit8, s=fit8$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat9 <- predict(fit9, s=fit9$lambda.1se, newx=x1)
yhat10 <- predict(fit10, s=fit10$lambda.1se, newx=x1)

mse0 <- mean((y1 - yhat0)^2)
mse1 <- mean((y1 - yhat1)^2)
mse2 <- mean((y1 - yhat2)^2)
mse3 <- mean((y1 - yhat3)^2)
mse4 <- mean((y1 - yhat4)^2)
mse5 <- mean((y1 - yhat5)^2)
mse6 <- mean((y1 - yhat6)^2)
mse7 <- mean((y1 - yhat7)^2)
mse8 <- mean((y1 - yhat8)^2)
mse9 <- mean((y1 - yhat9)^2)
mse10 <- mean((y1 - yhat10)^2)
```

EDIT : The plot in the code looks like [image: this]

Comment: For all  rows in every yhat I get 48.1531 and the values for all mse are 1003.14. Unfortunately it isnt possible for me to share data, however I can share the plot mentioned in the code.

Comment: What are the coefficients output from each of your models? If there is poor correlation between your dependent and independent variable the coefficients can be reduced to 0 for lasso and near 0 for ridge, which would return the mean of the dependent var for each row. Also could you supply a small sample of your data?

Comment: Can you supply just the coefficients returned by your model? Also is the mean of your dependent var 48.1531 by any chance? `mean(c201512_TOTAL_MARGIN)`

Comment: You are right the mean for response is 48.1531. Could you explain what that means?

Comment: It means lambda is too high in your prediction function: See here for details: https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html

Comment: Check that your data is right. In particular, one of your coefficients is heading off to 8000. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `s=fit0$lambda.min` rather than `s=fit0$lambda.1se` in your predict function. Your coefficients drop to 0 on lasso very quickly so `s=fit0$lambda.1se` might be too high a penalising factor. lambda determines the weight of penalisation for your coefficients, if it is too high your coefficients will be zero and the prediction will be equal to the intercept, which is the mean of the dependent variable e.g. Y= 0.48 + 0*X

Comment: You are right, I do get some sort of predictions once I change to lambda.min .
My original data has been artificially widened and flattened. i.e to get more variables for prediction I converted catagorical columns to numerical, which lead to a fairly sparse matrix of 3-4k columns. Do you think that might be the cause of it?

Comment: Yes that might be a cause because I imagine it weakens the correlation between the dependent and independent variables. I may also just simply be that your independent var isn't a great predictor of your dependent var. What you have to remember with elastic net type regression is its a balance between reducing the least likelihood (or OLS) loss function and reducing the size of the coefficients. If X is not correlated with Y strongly then even at small levels of lambda the coefficients can be reduced to 0 or near 0